# Magento 1.9.2. - If the current customer does not place an order in a pre-established time

Tags: magento-1.9, php, orders, customer

I would like to create an **if** with php where I assign an action if the current customer registered on my site in magento does not place an order after 6 months from his last order.

```
if(customer not place an order in six months){
//action
} else { //ok }
```

How can I do?

this is my try:

`Sure: $_customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
        $orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
            ->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $_customer->getId())
            ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->setPageSize(1);`

```
    $date_order_creation=$orders->getFirstItem()->getCreatedAt();
    $previous_date = date('Y-m-d');

    $date_a = new DateTime($date_order_creation);
    $date_b = new DateTime($previous_date);
    $interval = date_diff($date_a,$date_b);

    if($interval->format('%d') > 1){


        echo 'more 1 day';
    }else{

        echo 'not yet 1 day';
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code :

```
<?php
$_customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

$orders = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
    ->addFieldToSelect('*')
    ->addFieldToFilter('customer_id', $_customer->getId())
    ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')
    ->setPageSize(1);

$date_order_creation=$orders->getFirstItem()->getCreatedAt();
$date_now = date('Y-m-d');

$date_a = new DateTime($date_order_creation);
$date_b = new DateTime($date_now);
$interval = date_diff($date_b,$date_a);

if($interval->format('%m') >=6){
    echo '6 months from this order';
}else{

    echo 'not yet 6 months';
}
```

?>

Tell me if it works. Happy Coding !!!

Comment: Hi sami. i testing in this moment your solution. I'll let you know as soon as possible. Thanks for the help

Comment: hey @Gabriel91 good luck :D

Comment: @sami23 just one improvement suggestion: Magento's timezone (from the db: $order->getCreatedAt()) could be different than php's (date function). You could use magento's functions to calculate the time difference (even if a few hours are nothing in front of 6 months).

Comment: @FraH yes you are right ;)

Comment: Hi guys! I finished trying your function. Only a question, this function takes the date of the last order placed by the right customer?

Because at the moment I tried to run the code like this:
if ($ interval-> format ('% d') == 1) {
echo 'order by 1 day';
} Else {

echo 'not yet 1 day';
}

but despite the last order has already passed more than a day, the php continues to take the phrase 'not yet 1 day'.
Is it because of the time problem in the php? How can I do more precisely?

Comment: @Gabriel91 i have a mistake in my code i just edit you can check now

Comment: Hi, i have the same issue. I tried this in local with xampp. I paste your code but i have the same result. For him, not one day has passed since my last order :(

Comment: maybe is because for the wrong time in the php as he said Fra H?

Comment: can you share you code @Gabriel91

Comment: i update my question with the code that i used

Comment: @Gabriel91 i check your code and it work fine . You must login as a customer who had placed the order . try it and let me know

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81109/discussion-between-sami23-and-gabriel91).